# Error during the installation of package angular-google-maps

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

So when i try to install angular-google-maps package with this command :

```
meteor add angularui:angular-google-maps
```

i got this error, any help ?

> mise_server.js:165
>         throw error;
>         ^
>
> Error: unexpected eof
>       at decorate (C:\Users\Harbaoui\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\abstract.js:67:36)
>       at Extract.Abstract.error (C:\Users\Harbaoui\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\abstract.js:61:12)
>       at Extract._streamEnd (C:\Users\Harbaoui\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\tar\lib\extract.js:91:35)
>       at BlockStream. (C:\Users\Harbaoui\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:51:8)
>       at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
>       at BlockStream.emit (events.js:166:7)
>       at BlockStream._emitChunk (C:\Users\Harbaoui\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\block-stream\block-stream.js:203:10)
>       at BlockStream.resume (C:\Users\Harbaoui\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\block-stream\block-stream.js:58:15)
>       at Extract.Reader.resume (C:\Users\Harbaoui\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\reader.js:242:34)
>       at Entry. (C:\Users\Harbaoui\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:261:8)
>       at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
>       at Entry.emit (events.js:166:7)
>       at Entry.resume (C:\Users\Harbaoui\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\tar\lib\entry.js:93:8)
>       at resume (C:\Users\Harbaoui\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\collect.js:62:16)
>       at unblockEntry (C:\Users\Harbaoui\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\collect.js:43:28)
>       at Entry. (C:\Users\Harbaoui\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\collect.js:47:9)
>       at FileWriter. (C:\Users\Harbaoui\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\dir-writer.js:146:11)
>       at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
>       at FileWriter.emit (events.js:166:7)
>       at WriteStream. (C:\Users\Harbaoui\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\file-writer.js:45:10)
>       at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>       at WriteStream.emit (events.js:169:7)
>       at C:\Users\Harbaoui\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:205:14
>       at C:\Users\Harbaoui\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:232:16
>       at C:\Users\Harbaoui\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:232:16
>       at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)

Comment: Can you share more information?  maybe add a reproduction?